# Backdrop authentication function missing

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, kcfinder, backdrop

I am using Backdrop CMS 1.10.1 with CiviCRM 5.2.2 and I am having trouble with the kcfinder, when uploading and inserting images, both into CiviMail and CiviContribute.

The initial problem was a 500 error.  Based on this bit of the log,

`[Thu Jul 05 16:53:47.624995 2018] [fcgid:warn] [pid 6591] [client ] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in [site]/public_html/modules/civicrm/packages/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php:67`

I traced it down to this switch statement in /kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php

`switch ($config->userFramework) {
    case 'Drupal':
    case 'Drupal6':
      $auth_function = 'authenticate_drupal';
      break;
    case 'Joomla':
      $auth_function = 'authenticate_joomla';
      break;
    case 'WordPress':
      $auth_function = 'authenticate_wordpress';
      break;
    }`

This is missing the case for Backdrop, so $authfunction never got assigned to a string.  I tried to add a case for Backdrop, as well as the authenticate_backdrop function, but I don't know how to make it work.  First, I tried making the authenticate_backdrop function the same as authenticate_drupal, but it gives me the error:

`You must be logged in with proper permissions to edit, add, or delete uploaded images.`

I removed everything except the permission check from the function, so that it just looks like this:

`function authenticate_backdrop($config) {
  // check if user has access permission...
  if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('access CiviCRM')) {
    error_log("There is permission.")
    return true;
  }
}`

It gives me permission, and allows me to upload an image and insert it. Here is the original file with the authenticate functions for drupal, joomla and wordpress.  https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/blob/master/kcfinder/integration/civicrm.php

What is the correct way to implement `authenticate_backdrop`?  It is okay to just have the CRM_Core_Permission::check?

Comment: You might be right, but perhaps there's something we're missing. I don't really understand what's going on there. The drupal function is confusing and seems to have a whole lot of cruft that isn't being used. $base_url isn't being used. You might need to include the boostrap so we're sure to get the logged in user.

Comment: I checked and I think now that it has to bootstrap Backdrop otherwise it'll always return true.

Comment: Can you test this PR/patch? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/216

Comment: @herb The PR/patch works.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments above, this bug was fixed by @herb in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-packages/pull/216